# Matching two sets of data, add rows when necessary

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, excel, matching

I am working on a large sets of data. Each set of data have three rows, my job is to match the first two rows. My difficulty is this, if row 1&2 doesn't match, I need to create a new row for next set of data.  So in the beginning, the data looks like this:

```
     A        
1    00             
2   A001     
3    Y    
4    00
5   A002
6    N
```

And as you can see, not only A1 & A4 needs to match, but also A2 & A5, so because A2 & A5 don't match, I need to create a new row for it.  So the result will look like this:

```
     A       B
1    00            
2   A001  
3    Y
4            00
5           A002
6            N
```

I don't know any other way other than manually adding rows, and I need to combine 80 sets of data, so if anyone could help me with this, I will be so thankful!!

Comment: I might think along the lines of Normalizing the data, creating rows with three columns that look like  00-A001-Y  and  00-A002-N.   And then matching on columns 1 and 2...

Comment: is the first column ID which holds number 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ...?

Comment: Don, thank you for replying. Is there an easier way to do it thou? It's a lot of data to matching by hand...

Comment: Echo, that 1,2,3,4 is just my way to show the row number in excel, actual data starts at column A.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have 80 sets of data. Does it means that you have 240 rows in your table? If so maybe creating a plsql table is a solution.

Each row of the plsql table has 3 columns (the 3 rows of 1 data set).

From the table you select each time 3 rows; and these rows you put into the plsql table.
When the plsql table is filled, then you use a loop in a loop (2 loops) through the plsql table. So you can compare each record from table 1 with the records of table2. And if they don't match you can do your thing.

Comment: Hi, wireman. I am not pro on programming.  Do you mind provide me an E-mail address so you can send you an example and let me know if this table would work? If it will work, I will try my best to learn how to run it.

Comment: Jolene, I don't understand your question. I want to make an example procedure for you, but i don't know how to contact you.